# How can I get more than one 'tab' character in my textview?

Tags: android, spannablestring

I'm trying to display a log file in a textview, but the tab characters I have in the file aren't displaying properly.

```
SpannableStringBuilder span = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
span.setSpan(new TabStopSpan.Standard(600), 0, span.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE );


((TextView) findViewById(R.id.logText)).setText(span, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

What happens is that the first tab in a line displays properly, but all subsequent tabs show up as spaces. I have tried replacing '\t' with \u0009 but that still didn't work. I have also tried changing the tab span, but that also wasn't successful.

Comment: By using `new TabStopSpan.Standard(600)` you tell the `TextView` to insert a tab stop at `600` (pixels?) from the left margin of the `TextView`. Adding another `TabStopSpan` with the same margin offset is pointless. Try incrementing the margin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set them all:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 100)
    span.setSpan(new TabStopSpan.Standard(i), 0, span.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```